# How can I get some value in inner class in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I want to return some value depend on some value in inner class:

```
public boolean rename(File file) {
    new OnResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(AsyncResult<CharSequence> result) {
            // some codes

            // Here is what I want to do
            if (succeed) {
                // rename return true
            } else {
                // rename return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Return _where_ or _to who/what_?

Comment: Your inner class's method is never called. So if this was possible, `rename` wouldn't return anything?

Comment: @immibis this is the async result in android, I delete many code in my question

Comment: @roger So you want to start an AsyncTask, then wait until it's done? There is no point to that.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I call rename some place in my code, if   return true, I will refresh, if it returns false, I will do some error process

Comment: Who is invoking `OnResultListener#onResult`?

Answer (score -1):

You can't and it does not make sense. These are two distinct functions that may very well be called on different threads. What you have to do, if you insist on returning something, is that the "rename" function itself should receive a callback as a parameter that gets called upon success. That is, if the downstream call is asynchronous then the ones calling it should be too.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative would be to have a the calling function ("rename" in this case assuming it calls the function that notifies the OnResultListener) to wait on some mutex. Then, in the nested method upon receiving a result, you set some flag and then call notify() which would wake the thread held by the wait.

Comment: These are two different ways to tackle the problem.

Comment: In your other answer, you say _You can't and it does not make sense_. Which one is it?

Comment: You sure can't in the way you described. I gave you two alternative ways.